# How to vertically aligned my image to top in my React-native component

Tags: react-native

I'd like to top aligned my image in React-native. But don't know what to do. Here is my layout and its style:

```
class layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.toolbar}>
          <Text style={styles.left}>
            Left Button
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            This is my title
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.right}>
            Right Button
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Image style={styles.image}
            source={require('./back.jpg')}
            resizeMode="contain"
          ></Image>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#B5AC3a',
    height:64,
    flexDirection:'row'
  },
  left: {
    marginTop:30,
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  right: {
    marginTop:30,
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    marginTop:30,
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor:'#ffecff'
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 20,
    margin: 10,
    alignSelf:'center'
  }
});
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Apparently there are a lot of space between my image to top of my screen. I tried: **flex-start**. But doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks.

**P.S:** It's fine if I use **View** instead of **Image** like this:

```
class layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.toolbar}>
          <Text style={styles.left}>
            Left Button
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            This is my title
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.right}>
            Right Button
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <View style={styles.messageBox}>
           <Text>This is line one</Text>
           <Text>This is line two</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: In another word, is there something like **height: auto**?

Answer (score 3):

Your resizeMode='contain' on your image is conflicting with the dimensions you want to define in styles.image.
Simply remove resizeMode='contain' in your `<Image>` properties and it should work.

Something else: I would strongly advise you, depending on what you're trying to do, to use a ScrollView instead of the simple View when you have extendable content (namely anything that isn't completely static). This seems to be what you need.

Comment: If I remove resizeMode, how am I going to setup the scale mode?

Comment: You can change it either by using resizeMode, either by defining the dimensions of your image, but if you're going to use both, they will be a conflict.